# Synchronous Testing with Jasmine in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a service and defined an object Home inside that service. With Home object, I have defined a variable and a function like:

```
var Home = {};
Home.hasBeenCalled = false;
Home.searchDocClick = function(doctorData, locationData){
    // my code
    Home.hasBeenCalled = true;
}
```

Now in the my test file, I want to call serchDocClick function and test if hasBeenCalled is true or not, like inside describe

```
// beforeEach 

// test
it('searchDocClick() should produce data.', function () {

       // static data to test searchDocClick()
       var doctorData = {
            current_value: "Cardiologist",
            isSelected: true,
            type: "docs"
       }, locationData = {
            current_value: "Lahore",
            isSelected: true,
            type: "city"
       }

            Home.searchDocClick(doctorData, locationData);
            expect(Home.hasBeenCalled ).toBe(true);
        });
```

This is getting failed with error "expected false to equal true".
I think expect gets executed before call to searchDocClick() function complete.
I want my code in searchDocClick() function to be fully executed before expect gets executed.

Comment: The code you've posted is synchronous and should work. If you have problems with it, this means that you've omitted some essential details.

Comment: I'm with @estus. You've must have left out some essential details. If `searchDocClick` is indeed synchronous then there is no way for it to "not have finished" when your expect is run.

Comment: It works if Home.hasBeenCalled = true; is the first statement inside function. But it is added inside different if's and nested loops in my searchDocClick function.

Comment: @UmairJameel We cannot help you unless we see the full non-working example

Comment: Loops and ifs are synchronous. Please, post real code, because the things you've excluded are important.